# yet another "AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: authentication

I probably read like 10 different stories with the same error but still unable to make a rest call from my python code to get a token for my Azure Data Lake. Can you please help on this..not sure what am I missing..thank you

Here is how my python code looks:

```
import requests
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token"
params =  "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://management.core.windows.net&client_id=<CID>&client_secret=<CS>"

headers = {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
      }

response = requests.request("POST", url= url, headers=headers, params= params)
print(response.text)
```

"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'